# Difference between Maximum and Minimum of Square

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

What is the difference between finding the maximum and minimum capacity with square base with an open top when you have to find the width and height and volume?

Comment: How can a square have a volume?

Comment: @WeatherVane Anything can have a volume.

Comment: That was a hint to improve the question. In Flatland, there isn't even any *concept* of volume.

Comment: By square, do you mean cube?

Comment: yes a cube from optimization.